# Laravel escaped value in raw query

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I have this query:

```
UPDATE test SET cucc = 'akarmi' WHERE id IN (1, 2)
```

Laravel equivalent:

```
DB::table('test')
    ->whereIn('id', [1, 2])
    ->update(['cucc' => 'akarmi']);
```

But i'd like to append new values to column cucc:

```
UPDATE test SET cucc = CONCAT(cucc, 'akarmi') WHERE id IN (1, 2)
```

Laravel equivalent:

```
DB::table('test')
    ->whereIn('id', [1, 2])
    ->update(['cucc' => DB::raw("CONCAT(cucc, 'plus')")]);
```

But if the 'plus' string comes from a user input variable, it need to escape. I tried this:

```
DB::table('test')
    ->whereIn('id', [1, 2])
    ->update(['cucc' => DB::raw('CONCAT(cucc, ?)', 'plus')]);
```

But DB::raw not supports replace ? to escaped value.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

`DB::raw()` doesnt have a parameter for bindings but the query builder does

```
DB::table('test')
    ->whereRaw('id IN (?,?)')
    ->setBindings(['plus', 1, 2])
    ->update(['cucc' => DB::raw('CONCAT(cucc, ?)')]);
```

You can also use the bindings parameter of the `update()` method

(should work but didnt test it)

```
DB::table('test')
    ->whereIn('id', [1, 2])
    ->update(['cucc' => DB::raw('CONCAT(cucc, ?)')], ['plus']);
```

Comment: Unfortunately your suggestion does not works:  

`SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number (SQL: update `test` set `cucc` = CONCAT(cucc, 1) where `id` in (2, ?))`

Comment: @LayAndrás it's because the bindings from `whereIn()` are interfering. try with the named placeholder bindings instead. Edited the answer.

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters (SQL: update `test` set `cucc` = CONCAT(cucc, :cv) where `id` in (plus, ?))

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters (SQL: update `test` set `cucc` = CONCAT(cucc, :cv) where `id` in (1, 2))

Comment: @LayAndrás there, fixed it.